# JS: Как определить, что конкретная переменная - это Map/Set

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с проблемой, где мне нужно точно определить что конкретная переменная является *Set / Map / WeakSet / WeakMap*.
У массивов есть метод *Array.isArray()*, но я не нашёл такого метода у *Map / Set / ...* .
Они по своей сущности являются объектами, поэтому проверка на тип вернёт *'object'*

```
let value = new Set();
console.log(typeof value) // 'object'
```

Поэтому, чтобы определить, что данная переменная является *Set*-ом я писал так:

```
let value = new Set(); // тут может быть Map / WeakSet / WeakMap
if (typeof value === 'object') {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(value) === Object.getPrototypeOf(new Set())) { // Map / ...
        // выполняемый код
    }
}
```

Вопрос. Есть ли более приятный, читабельный вариант такой проверки? Как правильно определить, что переменная является *Set*-ом */* *Map*-ом */* *...*

Comment: `console.log(value instanceof Set);` [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: Также можно проверять `value.constructor.name` (`'Set'`).

Comment: value.toString()

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Объекты, созданные при помощи конструкторов `Map` и `Set` являются инстансами собственно `Map` и `Set`. А проверка на то, является ли объект инстансом чего-либо осуществляется при помощи оператора `instanceof`:

```js
const map = new Map();
const set = new Set();
const notMapNorSet = {};

// should print out "true, true, false, false"
document.write([
  set instanceof Set,
  map instanceof Map,
  notMapNorSet instanceof Map,
  notMapNorSet instanceof Set
].join(", "));
```